# Liberar acesso remoto MySQL 8

Tags: mysql

Estou testando a nova **versão 8 do MySql**, e me deparei com certa dificuldade na liberação de acesso remoto (especificadamente, usando o *Workbench*).

O que encontrei foi a [mesma pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50570592/mysql-8-remote-access), e apenas um [comentário](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50570592/mysql-8-remote-access#comment88153078_50570592) com um [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#upgrade-caching-sha2-password), mas nada esclarecedor.

Mesmo assim, tentei alguns detalhes, mas sem sucesso:

```
[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
```

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password
BY 'password';
```

---

Um pouco mais em pesquisa, encontrei alguns detalhes de liberação para IPv6, mas consta algo sobre IPv4 na Documentação oficial 8.0 ([link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ipv6-remote-connections.html)), e tentei diversas formas:

```
[mysqld]
bind_address = *

[mysqld]
bind_address = 0.0.0.0

[mysqld]
bind_address = 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0
```

---

Contudo, até o momento não consegui fazer a liberação.

Comment: Veja se ajuda: https://www.variphy.com/kb/how-to-enable-connections-to-mysql-from-remote-machine

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo Já tentei... de várias e várias formas! rs... aí comecei pesquisar especificadamente para MySql 8, foi onde fui achando essas novas questões.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O bind_address pode ser removido ou substituido por * e deve-se criar um usuário com acesso global (usando o wildcard %) ou então especificar o host que poderá conectar ao mesmo.

Caso use Mysql < 8 ou MariaDB 10.X:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Caso use Mysql >= 8

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALTER ROUTINE, ALTER, SHOW VIEW, SHOW DATABASES, SELECT, PROCESS, EXECUTE ON . TO 'root'@'%';
```

Comment: Engraçado, não era pra acontecer. Tente instalar algum mysql client no servidor como o HeidiSQL ou o phpMyAdmin e adicione por lá

Comment: Na própria documentação do MySQL 8 fala pra usar esse comando. Provavelmente é algum erro seu
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ipv6-remote-connections.html

Comment: O bind não precisa ser necessariamente *, pode ser omitido também. Realmente, no mysql 8 parece ter de criar o CREATE, em versões anteriores e no mariadb pode ser feito com grant, então o código seria:
`CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

Comment: Pode ter vários usuários com o mesmo nome e diferentes hostnames, % é um coriga, após o @ vem o hostname o qual ele pertence, você pode ter 'root' com diferentes hostnames e diferentes senhas.
A resposta está correta, provavelmente é algum erro no seu lado, inclusive fiz os testes.

Comment: Acabei de re-instalar o mysql 8 e funcionou corretamente. Removi o bind e rodei as seguintes queries:
CREATE USER 'teste'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '123';
GRANT ALTER ROUTINE, ALTER, SHOW VIEW, SHOW DATABASES, SELECT, PROCESS, EXECUTE  ON *.* TO 'teste'@'%';

Como falei anteriormente, está correta a resposta, verifique se o firewall está desativado ou com as regras corretas.

Comment: Encontrei o erro. O problema foi não ter criado o user "root", o que é necessário. Criando o user "root", executei  `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';`, o seu dá erro pois tem `IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` e o MySQL não aceita essa criação direta de usuário pelo `GRANT`, assim, elimina o `IDENTIFIED BY` da sequência.
Corrija sua resposta que vou marcar como resolvida. Mas quando for postar, é interessante detalhar o máximo possível, pois dessa forma fica um bom conteúdo para pesquisa e auxílio. Valeu!

Comment: A resposta foi corrigida, poderia marcar como correta?